# R2openbugs bugs() winepath error: No such file or directory

Tags: r, macos, wine, openbugs

My mac system is OS X El Capitan 10.11.6. I installed OpenBUGs using Winebottler(version 1.8.6) and Wine.

When I tried to call OpenBUGS  using R, the following error occurred:

```
sh: /opt/local/bin/winepath: No such file or directory
Error in system(paste(WINEPATH, "-w", x), intern = TRUE) : error in running command
```

Here are my R code:
    #Load the OpenBUGS Package - make sure XQuartz is running
    library(R2OpenBUGS)

```
#schools data in the R2OpenBUGS library
data(schools)

#define the model
nummodel <- function(){
       for (j in 1:J){
         y[j] ~ dnorm (theta[j], tau.y[j])
         theta[j] ~ dnorm (mu.theta, tau.theta)
         tau.y[j] <- pow(sigma.y[j], -2)}
       mu.theta ~ dnorm (0.0, 1.0E-6)
       tau.theta <- pow(sigma.theta, -2)
       sigma.theta ~ dunif (0, 1000)
 }

# write the model code out to a file
write.model(nummodel, "nummodel.txt")
model.file1 = paste(getwd(),"nummodel.txt", sep="/")
## and let's take a look:
file.show("nummodel.txt")

#prepare the data for input into OpenBUGS
J <- nrow(schools)
y <- schools$estimate
sigma.y <- schools$sd
data <- list ("J", "y", "sigma.y")

#initialization of variables
inits <- function(){
  list(theta = rnorm(J, 0, 100), mu.theta = rnorm(1, 0, 100),sigma.theta = runif(1, 0, 100))}

#set the WINE working directory and the directory to OpenBUGS - change   the OpenBUGS.exe location as necessary
WINE="/opt/local/bin/wine"
WINEPATH="/opt/local/bin/winepath"
OpenBUGS.pgm="/Users/[username]/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/OpenBUGS/OpenBUGS323/OpenBUGS.exe"


#these are the parameters to save
parameters = c("theta", "mu.theta", "sigma.theta")

#run the model
schools.sim <- bugs(data, inits, model.file = model.file1,parameters=parameters,n.chains = 3, n.iter = 1000, OpenBUGS.pgm=OpenBUGS.pgm, WINE=WINE, WINEPATH=WINEPATH,useWINE=T)

#R will pause. When model is complete a prompt will reappear
print(schools.sim)
```

I think that the problem may be how I specify the Wine and winepath working directory.

Could someone give me some advice please?